# Need help updating several of the meta names within two DB tables using PHPMyAdmin Operations tab

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I imported users and usermeta tables from one Wordpress database into a new database with a different table name. Now I need to update several of the meta names within those two tables using the Operations tab.

As you can see here (http://d.pr/i/1bQA9) **let_ needs** to be updates to **6FmD4_** - **Can someone tell me how to do that in PHPMyadmin without going through the each of the 18,000 users individually?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)  will help you to replace string in db with a different string. Remember do preform a "dry run" first before you preform a live replace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @batz, I just edited the file via a text editor and then re-imported the tables.  I'll try the plugin in the future.  Thanks again!